# Understanding the partition function

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

I have been trying, as a toy problem, to implement in either the Python or Haskell programming languages functions to calculate the [partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29) for a number and the count of those partitions. I have no mathematical background, so I'm probably making silly mistakes when trying to understand some of these concepts I've never been exposed to before.

As I understand it from reading about the [partition function on Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionP.html), the partition function $P(n)$ is what gives the count of partitions for a given number. The function is given as:
$$
P(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k+1}[P(n-\frac{1}{2}k(3k-1))+P(n-\frac{1}{2}k(3k+1))]
$$
So, I try to solve by hand for $P(1)=1$; but I just can't do it!
$$
P(1) = \sum_{} 1(P(0)+P(-1))
$$$$
P(1) = \sum_{} 0+0
$$$$
P(1) = 0
$$

This is obviously not right. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I believe that $P(0)$ is taken to be equal to 1 by convention.

Comment: @mhum Well that would certainly explain things. I assumed it would be 0 since the sum of an empty set is 0. Right? k=1 and n=0 means the result is 0. I'm not wrong about that, at least? And what is P(-1) supposed to be?

Comment: Okay, I see that in the Wikipedia in the article, now. P(0)=1 and P(negative number)=0. If you want to take credit, mhum, feel free to post as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not at all sure you're interested in this, but it is an alternative formulation that may be more straightforward to understand and possibly to compute.

Let $P(n, m)$ be the number of partitions of the number $n$ into parts that are of size $m$ or larger.  Then $$P(n,m) = \sum_{i=m}^n P(n-i, i)$$ whenever $n>0$.

The idea here is that we can extract from $n$ a single part of size $i$ between $m$ and $n$, and then having done so we need to partition the remainder, $n-i$. To avoid counting any partition more than once, we require that the parts be extracted in order of increasing size, so after extracting a part of size $i$, we require that all subsequent parts be of size at least $i$.

The base cases are only a little tricky: $$\begin{align}
P(n, m) &= 0 & \text{whenever $n<0$}\\
P(0, m) &= 1 & \\
\end{align}
$$

Also, an obvious optimization is
$$\begin{align}
P(n, m) &= 1 & \text{whenever $\frac n2< m< n$}\\
\end{align}
$$ because there is no way to partition a number $n$ into parts strictly larger than $\frac n2$, except by doing so trivially, into exactly one part.

The partition function itself is then simply $P(n,1)$, the number of partitions of $n$ into parts of size at least 1.

Here is $P(n)$ implemented in Haskell:

```
p :: Int -> Int
p =
  let
    p' m n
      | n < 0  = 0
      | n == 0 = 1
      | otherwise = sum [p' i (n - i) | i <- [m..n]]
  in
    p' 1
```

Comment: I gave so much context in my question because I was hoping for an answer like this.

Comment: @arussell84 I'm glad I was able to help.

Comment: Souldn't that be: "P(n,m)=1 whenever n/2 < m < n"  That is a equals one and not zero above?

Answer (score 2):

By convention, $P(0)=1$ and $P(n) = 0$ for $n<0$.

Comment: Thanks again for getting me to a working state! I am ultimately implementing MJD's solution since it is, in fact, quite a bit simpler than what I was trying in my original question.